# Check if Mobile Device has Automatic Time Zone enabled using ngCordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova, ionic-v1

Ionic v1 app needs to check if the Mobile Device (Android or iOS) has Automatic Time Zone enabled, how can I do that? I imagine it's done using ngCordova.

For some actions, Automatic Time Zone has to be enabled so the server will receive real date and time instead of fake ones. I won't allow the user to proceed if it's disabled.

Comment: You could be a hero and write a plugin that allows the cordova community to access `android.provider.Settings.Global`.  Last time I checked one doesn't exist.  The better option for your issue is to just use unix time and never have to worry about timezones again.

Comment: @BShaps I'm on my way to do that plugin!

Comment: @BShaps bytheway, even if I use unix time, i'm still letting the user fake his date and time settings and that is a problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created [this ngcordova plugin](https://github.com/edsonhoraciojunior/verify-automatic-date-time-zone) to do that, at the moment it only supports Android. iOS is not supported because it doesn't expose iPhone's  Date and Time settings programatically.

#### Usage

```
window.VerifyAutomaticDateTimeZone.isAutomaticChecked(function(isIt){
  if (isIt == 'true') {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
});
```

In case `window.VerifyAutomaticDateTimeZone` is undefined, wrap the call with `$ionicPlatform.ready` or `ionic.Platform.ready`

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
    // code here...
});
```